# Update text on button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have such button on my page (for showing current total in shopping cart):

```
    <div class="col s2 offset-s4 valign" id="shoppingCart">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat no-margin white-text right" th:inline="text"><i class="material-icons right">shopping_cart</i>[[@{${total}+' руб'}]]</a>
    </div>
```

Written function for updating total number on that button:

```
function updateShoppingCart(newTotal) {
    var $div = $("#shoppingCart");

    var $a = $("<a class='waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat no-margin white-text right'></a>");
    var $i = $("<i class='material-icons right'>shopping_cart</i>");
    var $string = formatDecimal(newTotal,',','.') + " руб";

    $a.append($i);
    $a.append($string);

    $div.children().remove();
    $div.append($a);
}
```

But it does not work. Please help find bug or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What does formatDecimal() do?

Comment: Just format number...

Comment: Can you debug your JS, does your script make it pass this function?

Comment: Sure thing, debugged about hour. formatDecimal works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot more efficient to set `$div = $('#shoppingCart');`; in the global scope and use that var instead. This way your JS won't search through your entire DOM every time the function is called.

Your stuff doesn't work because your `var`s are very odd. I believe what you want to achieve is this:

**HTML**

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat no-margin white-text right" th:inline="text">
  <i class="material-icons right">shopping_cart</i>
  <span>[[@{${total}+' руб'}]]</span>
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function updateShoppingCart(newTotal) {
    var $div = $("#shoppingCart");

    var $a = $("a", $div); //select the <a> within the shoppingcart div
    var $i = $("i", $div); //select the <i> within the shoppingcart div
    var $span = $("span", $div); //select the newly added span
    var newPrice = formatDecimal(newTotal,',','.') + " руб";

    $span.text(newPrice);
}
```

I kept the `$a` and `$i` in as examples, but I don't see a need for you to use them or completely replace them, since you only want to change the text. By using a span, you can target the price without replacing all the html.

On a sidenote, the `$` is generally used to state a var is a jquery object. `string`  is not a jquery object in this scenario, so the `$` there is a bit odd.

On a sidenote, if you want to replace html within an element, you should try doing it like so:

```
function updateShoppingCart(newTotal) {
    var $div = $("#shoppingCart");

    var newPrice = formatDecimal(newTotal,',','.') + " руб";
    //Create the new HTML as a string, not as an element
    var newHtml= '<a href="#" class="somethingClass"><i>Shopping_cart</i>'+newPrice+'</a>';

    //empties div beforehand current html, no seperate removal needed.
    //Then places the html string within the element
    $div .html(newHtml); 
}
```

[See working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8m0wn1m8/2/)

Comment: Thanks mate, can't check your advice right now, out of my comp now

Comment: Thanks! Works fine